# WCF REST API - Error when consuming rest API "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key:

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, azure

I created a WCF REST API and published it to Windows Azure. The code works perfectly in Azure emulator. But, when trying to consume the API GET method through the browser I get the following error:

```
    [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
    Parameter name: key]
    System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument) +48
    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key) +38
    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value) +20
    System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.WebHttpDispatchOperationSelector..ctor(ServiceEndpoint    
endpoint) +2459
   System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior.GetOperationSelector(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) +125
   System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher) +1955
   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost) +4245
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime() +119
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +45
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +553
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +350
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +1614

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/RestServiceImpl.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key.]
   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +911
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +525
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult ar) +98
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +126
```

From the stack trace it seems that the error is related to the endpoint of the service.
After more investigation, when dropping the  element from the web.config this error disappear and another error occurs. But in every example that I saw  does appear in the web.config.
This is my web config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <services> 
          <service name="RestService.RestServiceImpl"     
                   behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
          <endpoint address="" 
                    binding="webHttpBinding" 
                    contract="RestService.IRestServiceImpl"                 
                    behaviorConfiguration="web">
          </endpoint>    
        </service>
      </services>
      <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="web">
              <webHttp />
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
       </behaviors>
       <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
     </system.serviceModel>
     <system.webServer>
       <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
     </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a base address defined for your service to wait on.

```
<services> 
    <service name="RestService.RestServiceImpl"  behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <host>
            <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://localhost:1234/MyWCF/"/>
            </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" 
            binding="webHttpBinding" 
            contract="RestService.IRestServiceImpl"                 
            behaviorConfiguration="web">
        </endpoint>    
    </service>
</services>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As I mentioned, my code works when running in Azure emulator on my local host. I tried your answer but it didn't work out, my problem occur only when deploying to Azure.